# Jquery set optgroup selected value

Tags: jquery, optgroup

I am not sure how to set the optgroup selected value, making sure the option selected has the correct label. The problem that i am having is that I have two labels but the options for each can be the same.

Label 1 = Honda
Label 2 = Toyota

Options for both:

option 1 = "Red"
option 2 ="Blue" ...

I want to set the selected option to Blue under the Honda label on document.ready().
Currently when i try to set the option as selected the last item using "Blue" is the one that is selected in this case that is Blue under the Toyota label.

I have tried:

```
var color ="Blue";
var make ="Honda";
var test = $('#car_selector optgroup[label='+make+'] option[value="'+color+'"]')
test.prop('selected', true);

<select>
 <optgroup label="Honda">
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Toyota">
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: I posted an answer, but your jQuery selector string looks close, you just need to properly set up/escape the quotation marks before `make`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have markup similar to this:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Honda">
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

This JS will work:

```
var make = 'Honda';
var color = 'red';

var optgroup = $('select optgroup[label="'+make+'"]')
var option = optgroup.find('option[value="'+color+'"]')

option.attr('selected', true)
```

[JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/mowewa/2/edit?js,output)

**EDIT** As I mentioned in comment, it was just an error properly quotating the `make` variable into the selector.

Comment: I believe what you posted will only work if you have different values for all the labels i have similar values for the different labels. I edited post to include what html looks like.

Comment: Thank you for this, i figured my selector was wrong but this makes more sense.